# How to make a single bundle for a multipage app with webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

We have a multi-page MVC app. Client-side scripts are written in Typescript. For now we do not use webpack at all. We have a separate typescript module for each page which contains page-specific code. Also we have a bunch of "common" modules which are imported by "page" modules. For now we have typescript configured for compiling each module in out Typescript folder and outputting the results to the wwwroot preserving their folder structure. The modules are compiled in SystemJS format, they are assigned with names according to their path and the SystemJS on the client side can load them. I.e. the page will have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      SystemJS.import('Home/Home.Index').then(function(m) {
        m.initialize();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

SystemJS acquires the module (download it from host if neccessary) and we can execute initialization function from the module.

That works fine but has a downside that we can't use 3rd party imports this way. I.e. if i want to import some vendor module in my scripts then i'll have to somehow provide it to the page where the script will be executed. I'll have to copy it to the wwwroot dir, then add it as the `<script>` tag and make some workarounds in typescript code to get access to its functions.

---

This leads me to the webpack. I want all my modules to be combined into the single bundle with all the 3rd party imports included to be loaded one time by user and cached by the browser. On each page i want to call specific module and run it's initialize function. Unfortunately i can't find a way to do it. Webpack manuals state that i should make different entry points for different pages but this leads to tens of bundles which are largely the same (as "page" modules reference "common" modules a lot and in each bundle "common" modules get repeated) and this dissolves the whole idea of bundling.

I've tried `"splitChunks"` optimization but while it actually gets rid of duplication it produces unpredictable amount of files which i can't include in page statically as the files can appear or change names if dependencies in the code change.

---

Again, what i want is a single bundle and calling a specific function from it on the page.